# How to handling cookies to keep user logged in with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cookies

Im new to Swift and not very advanced. 
I have WKWebView that loads my school's Moodle page. I log in and do stuff inside, but after I kill the app and start it again; it asks for the log in details again, instead of staying logged in.

I tried with a different website (youtube) and it keeps me logged in even after I kill the app. So Im assuming its in the way website cookies work

This is the response I get from the request.

```
    Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x14f734f10> { URL: https://moodle.ucl.ac.uk/ } { status code: 200, headers {
"Accept-Ranges" = none;
"Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, no-transform";
Connection = close;
"Content-Language" = en;
"Content-Script-Type" = "text/javascript";
"Content-Style-Type" = "text/css";
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Wed, 02 Dec 2015 14:35:47 GMT";
Expires = "Mon, 20 Aug 1969 09:23:00 GMT";
"Last-Modified" = "Wed, 02 Dec 2015 14:35:47 GMT";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)";
"Set-Cookie" = "MoodleSessionuclmoodle2=pn5n2akomeen3qgkjdel5fspv2; path=/; secure";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Frame-Options" = sameorigin;
"X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=edge";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use NSDefaultUser or Keychain to store user logged in and once they tapped just delete the key.

## [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

Now this method is good if you want to keep your data live as long as the app is installed, once the app is removed this will reset automatically. You also have the option to update the value of the key if you wish, here is how you do NSUserDefault:

I always like to register my NSUserDeafult to default setting,  a lot of people just continue with the second step without registering.

**Register NSUserDefault in AppDelgate.swift**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["valueName": AnyObject])
```

**Set Value** to your NSUserDefault, this depends on what type of data you're storing, should match the one with your registration if you did register. (Example of Boolean data type below)

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "valueName") //Bool Data Type
```

Make sure you synchronize once you set the value to the NSUserDefault, this way it will update instantly, otherwise it will update when it get a chance.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**Receive Value:** this will receive boolean value since we set boolean and register boolean.

```
let Variable: Bool! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("valueName")
```

---

**[Keychain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YTlXk3Z36k),** 
Sergey Kargopolov will walk you through how to use a third party to use swift keychain. Otherwise, you can take even [harder challenge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/) and create one yourself.

---

Please ask any question you may have. :)

Comment: Thank you sir! I will give it a try.